# How to use postman to upload DBRef data in json?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-restful

I'm trying to post data to mongodb using postman but I don't know the proper convention for uploading the reference to a image file in the fs.files bucket. Basically, the file is already in the database, I'm just trying to post a new user with the reference to the image.

Here is my model:

```
class Users(db.Document):
    _id = db.StringField()
    name = db.StringField()
    picture = db.FileField()
    email = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    meta = {'collection': 'Users'}
```

In postman, I try to post data like so:

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"name" : "John Doe",
"picture": [{"$id": "5e6a...f9q102"}], #This is the reference id for the image already in the database, in fs.files
"password" : "<hashed pw>",
"email" : "example@example.com"
}
```

I'm using flask restful api so in the python script, the post function is defined like so:

```
def post(self):
    body = request.get_json()
    print (body)
    user = Users()
    user = Users(**body).save()
    return 'Successful Upload', 200
```

I get the error when I try with the above convention:

```
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Users:None) ('list' object has no attribute
    'grid_id': ['picture'])
```

How do I post a new user in postman? Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Validation error. The database was accepting JSON in a particular format than what I was posting. And the way I was processing the post request was also incorrect. This is the format it expected:

```
{
    ...,
    "picture" = {"$ref": "fs.files", 
                 "$id": ObjectId("5e6a...f9q102")},
    ...
}
```

Postman cannot accept the above format, instead, it accepted this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "picture": {"$ref": "fs.files", "$id": {"$oid": "5e6a...f9q102"}}, 
    "password" : "<hashed pw>",
    "email" : "example@example.com"
}
```

To make this work I changed the model to look this so in my flask app:

```
class Users(db.Document):
    _id = db.StringField()
    name = db.StringField()
    picture = db.ReferenceField('fs.files') #I changed this to a reference field because it holds the reference for the file and not the actual file in the database
    upload_picture = db.FileField() #I added this field so I can still upload pics via flask and via this document
    email = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    meta = {'collection': 'Users'}
```

Then I had to add this import and change the code so that it would read the input as JSON and transfer the reference value of picture to `ObjectId(id)` so that it matches the format the database was expecting.

```
from bson.json_util import loads

def post(self):
        body = str(request.get_json())
        x = body.replace("'", '"') #replace single quotes as double quotes to match JSON format
        data = loads(x)
        officer = Officers(**data).save()
        return 'Successful Upload', 200
```

Then voila, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a bit your code

Add these imports:

```
from mongoengine.fields import ImageGridFsProxy
from mongoengine import ReferenceField, DynamicDocument
from bson.dbref import DBRef
from bson import ObjectId
```

Modify your class `picture` field definition + add extra class `fs`

```
class Fs(DynamicDocument):
    #Add 'db_alias':'default' to meta
    meta = {'collection': 'fs.files'}

class Users(Document):
    ...
    picture = ReferenceField('Fs', dbref=True)
    ...
```

Now, you need to create new instance for `DBRef` this way:

```
def post(self):
    body = request.get_json()
    body["picture"] = DBRef('fs.files', ObjectId(body["picture"]))

    #mongoengine assumes `ObjectId('xxx')` already exists in `fs.files`. 
    #If you want to check, run below code:
    #if Fs.objects(_id=body["picture"].id).first() is None:
    #    return 'Picture ' + str(body["picture"].id) + ' not found', 400

    user = Users(**body).save()
    return 'Successful Upload', 200
```

At the end, if you need to read picture content:

```
image = ImageGridFsProxy(grid_id=ObjectId('xxx'))
f = open("image.png", "wb")
f.write(image.read())
f.close()
```